# Is there a way to use browserify-shim without package.json?

Tags: gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

I need to use browserify-shim for some of my browserify dependencies, but I can't edit my package.json.  I'm using browserify inside of gulp.  It is possible to specify all of the package.json portion exclusibely form the API?  I'm envisioning something like this:

```
return gulp.src('glob/path/to/my/main/js/file.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
        debug: false,
        transform: ['browserify-shim'],
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                exports: 'jQuery'
            }
        }
    }));
```

Then, my output with repalce `var $ = require('jquery');` with `var $ = jQuery;`, since we are now utilizing jQuery as a global.  Is this possible?  Whne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp       = require('gulp')
browserify = require('gulp-browserify')

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    var src = 'test.js'

    gulp.src(src)
        .pipe(browserify({
            shim: {
                jQuery: {
                    path: './bowser_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                    exports: '$'
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
})
```

**test.js**

```
$ = require('jQuery')

console.log($);
```

Comment: Using `gulp-browserify` is considered to be a moveton ( https://github.com/deepak1556/gulp-browserify#note-this-plugin-is-no-longer-maintained--checkout-the-recipes-by-gulp-team-for-reference-on-using-browserify-with-gulp) for now. It's blacklisted

Comment: I agree with @KolyaAy, `gulp-browserify` is now considered blacklisted and unsupported. Answer needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [exposify](https://github.com/thlorenz/exposify) transform in that case. browserify-shim is actially [based on it](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/blob/master/package.json#L44) and is written by the same guy.

E.g.:

```
return browserify('glob/path/to/my/main/js/file.js', { debug: false })
    .transform('exposify', { expose: {'jquery': 'jQuery' }})
```